# Comma 2022.07 Complete Edition not loading environment

Tags: raku, commaide

When I try to run bin commands in a project with the Complete Edition, comma isn't understanding the `#!/usr/bin/env raku` line and the commands are failing

I've run into this problem before. See https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/u0ix0n/if_you_are_on_mac_and_use_comma_ide_make_sure_you/

Except I can't fix it this time per suggestion in the link above because there is no "Full Disk Access" setting for Comma anymore.

What's weird is if I use the CT edition of Comma, I can run the scripts just fine.

Any fix for the Complete Edition?

Answer (score 3):

In the process of closing and re-opening CT/CP versions of Comma several times to try to troubleshoot this issue, the problem magically disappeared. I didn't change any settings. Keeping an eye on this.